# Pyspark databricks: how to format yyyymmdd column to show as mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: dataframe, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

in Azure databricks, pyspark
there is already an existing dataframe

df1

| Name | date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20210720 |
| B | 20231005 |
| C | 20190215 |

I hope the column date can be format to like below

| Name | date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 07/20/2021 |
| B | 10/05/2023 |
| C | 02/15/2019 |

How should I write the scripts??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can code something like the below, here am assuming the date column is of string type

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, to_date


data = [("20231030",), ("20231115",), ("20231225",)]
columns = ["date_string"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df = df.withColumn("to_date_format", to_date(df["date_string"], "yyyyMMdd"))
df = df.withColumn("formatted_date", date_format(df["to_date_format"], "dd/MM/yyyy"))

df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

output:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|date_string|to_date_format|formatted_date|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|   20231030|    2023-10-30|    30/10/2023|
|   20231115|    2023-11-15|    15/11/2023|
|   20231225|    2023-12-25|    25/12/2023|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- date_string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- to_date_format: date (nullable = true)
 |-- formatted_date: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: the dataframe has more than 10 thousand rows. If I used above codes, will all the date be formatted??

Comment: yes it wil apply the transformation on the entire column for each row